# Highchart Scatterplot with x axis only

Tags: highcharts, scatter

I am trying to use Highchart  to display scatter plot with x axis only. Plea see the attachment. I would like to plot along the x axis. Any directions is highly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `timeline` series type or a basic scatter with constant `y` values. For example:

```
const data = [1656316375158, 1656316385158, 1656316395158];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data.map(el => [el, 0])
    }],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0b3pk49v/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/timeline-series